# comma separated text into different arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net, csv

(VB.net)

I have A comma separated text  that looks like this 
[text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zRCG.png) .

What I want is to make it so **each line is its own array**, so one array would have `"name","password","255","255","0"` and another would have `"name","password","255","0","255"`.

I've got it reading fine and I can put it into one array it's just splitting them that's the problem. Is there also a way to make the program dim the arrays themselves. For example if there are three lines then have it dim three separate arrays. Any help would be great.

Comment: You are probably looking for a jagged array (or array of arrays), but even better would be a `List(Of String())` so you dont have to fret about the size.  Also `dim` is not a verb

Comment: Note that your names and passwords are never allowed to contain commas without breaking your code. You should either use a different delimiter or wrap them with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ and [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim records As String()() = (
    From line As String In File.ReadLines(data)
    Select line.Split(","c)
).ToArray()
```